# Is it possible to "unaccept" an answer?

Tags: support

Just wanted to know if it's possible to "un-accept" an answer.
I did not read such a thing in documentation.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see "click to unaccept this answer" on accept check mark for my questions, so... yes?..

Comment: cool thanks a lot !

Comment: Ask this because I get the case today and I was thinking it's hard to understand a thread when someone asks a question, mark it as resolved, and add comment. And 2-3 hours later delete everything =_